# var in class gives error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using var outside of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929492/using-var-outside-of-a-method)

```
class A {
string X;
}
// Proper
class A {
var X;
}
// Improper (gives error)
```

Why is it, that i cant have var type variable declare in Class and what can be done in order to achieve it OR what is an alternative ?

**In function/method, i can declare a var type variable,then why can't, i do it in class ?**

Thanks.

Comment: In function/method, i can declare a var type variable,then why can't, i do it in class ?

Comment: There is no need to do this; if you were able to it would just make the type of the variable less explicit, hence your code more obscure.  Perhaps you are misunderstanding the purpose of the var keyword.

Comment: Needless, annoying duplication when declaring class members: Dictionary<string, double> D = new Dictionary<string, double>();

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
// method variable
var X;
```

is **never** valid - even inside a method; you need immediate initialization to infer the type:

```
// method variable
var X = "abc"; // now a string
```

As for why this isn't available for *fields* with a field-initializer: simply, the spec says so. Now **why** the spec says so is another debate... I could check the [annotated spec](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765), but my suspicion would be simply that they are more *necessary* for method variables, where the logic is more complex (re LINQ etc). Also, they are *often* used with [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) (that being the **necessity** for their existence); but anonymous types can't be exposed on a public api... so you could have the very confusing:

```
private var foo = new { x = 123, y = "abc"}; // valid
public var bar = new { x = 123, y = "abc"}; // invalid
```

So all in all I'm happy with the current logic.

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* don't know the type of object your instance variable will hold, use `object`, not `var`. `var` doesn't mean "i don't know", it means "infer the type for me" - this is why it can never be used on class members.

Comment: but when i type in function/method i can declare a var type variable

Comment: @Rahul It works at method scope because the variable lives and dies within the block, therefore the compiler can easily infer its type. At class scope, the compiler would have to consider state, sequence, instances and all sorts of other factors.

Comment: Well Thanks. Can you suggest me some differences & similarities in object &  var from which i can decide whether or not i can use object type in my code.

Comment: @Rahul, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c) about `var` and `object`.

Comment: As Marc said, this doesn't really explain why it doesn't infer it when there *is* a field-initializer.

Answer (score 4):

Because C# doesn't support this level of type inferencing. Your alternatives are to use a language, such as F#, that does support this level of type inferencing or beg the C# team to implement the feature. I've got a pretty good guess which one you'll have more luck with...

Comment: using F# in not relevant for me neither is begging C# team.Looking forward for anything different than these two!

Comment: The reality is that C# doesn't support this feature. My point wasn't to switch languages, just that support is possible (e.g. F#) and the C# team chose not to implement "var" for anything other than local variables. Begging the C# team was me being tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 3):

var in C# is a implicitly typed local variable used to infer the type from the RHS of the given expression, which needs to be resolved at compile time. When you declare a var with no RHS value in the class definition, there is no way for the compiler to know the type that you are trying to assign to var.

C# doesn't support implicit typing for class variables.

Comment: var X = "Something"; // gives error still.

Comment: `var` is not allowed at class scope, period.

Answer (score 0):

Because the actual type of a var is inferred from the context in which it is used. For fields (class member variables), there is no such context.

Comment: There *can* be though, via a field-initializer

Answer (score 0):

You can argue that the intent is quite obvious if you would write `var _users = new List<User>()` as a field declaration.

The problem is that not all field declarations contains an assignment which is required to infer the type. (You might want to initialize a field through the constructor)

Mixing both `var` and normal type declarations would look like a nasty soup. Therefore it's not possible.

(at least that's my guess)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `var` keyword is only allowed for local variables.

It was introduced in the language to be able to handle an anonymous type, that only exists in a local scope. As the anonymous type is limited to the local scope, it makes sense to only allow the `var` keyword in a local scope.

Additionally, it never works to use the `var` keyword without specifying a value, as that is used to infer the data type:

```
var x = "asdf"; // works

var x; // doesn't work
```

The normal way of declaring a variable is using a specific data type. Use the `var` keyword when you can't specify a data type (e.g. when the type is anonymjous) or when the type is superflous (e.g. repeated literally in the value). Example:

```
var x = new { Key = 42, Name = "asdf" };

var y = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is all because of the Build order. You can declare var in only methods. Compiler builds everything but methods first and thats why the type of the object will be clear to the compiler if you use it inside of a method. Jon had a great answer about this but can't seem to find.