# Implicity typed class member

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, implicit-typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using var outside of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929492/using-var-outside-of-a-method)

I've searched for this a bit, but am not too sure of the search terms so didn't find anything.

Why can't i do this:

```
class foo
{
    var bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Guessing there must be a very good reason, but i can't think of it!

I'm more interested in the reasoning, rather than the because "C# doesn't let you" answer.

EDIT: Edited `Dictionary` declaration, sorry (just a typo in the example)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 reasons:

1. The Dictionary requires Key and Value generic parameters
2. You cannot write variables like this directly inside a class => you could use fields, properties or methods

So:

```
class foo
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

As to why you cannot do this:

```
class foo
{
    private var bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Eric Lippert has covered it in a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a type for the key, it should be:

```
class foo
{
    Dictionary<string,string> bar = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```

Edit: And it's not allowed to use "var" in case of class fields.

Comment: Fixed, it was because of the "var", which is only allowed in case of member variables.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary needs two parameters, a key type and a value type.

```
var bar = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Dictionary" means a collection of key/value pairs. In real-world, a dictionary of worlds is a book containing "Words" and "Definitions", here "Word" is key and "Definition" is value. So this is obvious that you can't ignore "value" when instantiating a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a class for mapping a set of keys to a set of values, so you need to specify a type parameter for both the key and value.  For example, if you want to lookup a share price based on its stock symbol, you might use:

```
var stocks = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
stocks.Add("MSFT", 25.5M);
stocks.Add("AAPL", 339.87M);
```