# Shorthand notation for class member initialization

Tags: c#

In a C# block, I can define and initialize a variable as follows:

```
var xyz = new Xyz();
```

The type of `xyz` will be set accordingly.

However, at the class level, I have to specify the type twice:

```
class Abc
{
    Xyz xyz = new Xyz();
}
```

Is there a shorthand syntax that avoids typing out the type name twice?

This isn't such a big deal with short types like `Xyz` but a shorter notation would help with LongTypeNames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a few particular types and want them shortened you can create an alias with a using statement, eg:

```
using ShortName = Abc.Xyz.ClassWithAVeryLongNameThatYouDontLikeTypingTooOften;
```

then within that file you could do something like:

```
class Abc
{
    ShortName xyz = new ShortName();
}
```

But as far as I know there's no `var` equivalent at the class level.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of this question: [Using var outside of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929492/using-var-outside-of-a-method)

Which contains a great in-depth answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx