# The name does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#

I'm a total noob in c#, since today. I couldn't find a good tutorial or anything, that could solve this obviously dumb problem. Basically, I try to translate a program from Python to C#. Normally in Python I define constants in the constructor. Where the hell should I put them in c#? I tried to put them in the constructor then I put them in Main(), because there was this error. But the error persists.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var _top = 0
    ...
    }
public string[] topToken()
    {
        if (_top < _tokens.Count())
        { return _tokens[_top];}
```

Comment: Which tutorials are you using? They all should cover member variables. Member variables are kind of fundamental to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_top` is declared inside `Main`, so it's not going to have visibility inside the `topToken` method. It's a local variable, scoped only to `Main`.

To give your variables visibility for the entire class, you need to declare them outside of any method.

Ex:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int someVariable; // all methods in SomeClass can see this

    public void DoIt() {
      // we can use someVariable here
    }
}
```

Note, by makeing someVariable public, it also means other we can access it directly. For example:

```
SomeClass x = new SomeClass();
x.someVariable = 42;
```

If you want to prevent this and only allow the methods/properties/etc. of the class to be able to see the `someVariable` variable, you can declare it as private.

In cases where you need a public variable, it's usually best to declare it like this (this is an example of an [auto-implemented property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeVariable { get; set; }

    public void DoIt() {
      // we can use SomeVariable here
    }
}
```

This uses

Comment: Ok, I get this, but where should it go, then? It has to be accessible within a whole class and also public.

Comment: See the example I added, I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok now it works, I just thought everything needs to be in a method, so first I tried to put it in the constructor.

Comment: @Adam - Glad to hear it.

Comment: But it means that I cannot just type var? - Why, the compiler can tell if it is a string or int?

Comment: You can't use var for class level variables. For an answer on why, you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929492/using-var-outside-of-a-method

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
const int _top = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    ...
    }
public string[] topToken()
    {
        if (_top < _tokens.Count())
        { return _tokens[_top];}
```

To make `_top` accessible throughout your class you have to declare it as a field or a constant. A field requires actual storage while a constant is simply replaced by the actual value by the compiler. As you described `_top` as a constant I decided to declare it as such.

If you need a field and not a constant you have to declare it `static` because it is accessed in a static method:

```
static int _top = 0;
```

Because there is no `public` or `protected` in the declaration of `_top` it is private to the class. If you prefer you can add `private` in front of the declaration but that will be the default if the visibility is missing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want `_top` to be available outside of the `Main` method, place it here:

```
int _top = 0; //here instead
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
}
public string[] topToken()
{
    if (_top < _tokens.Count())
    { return _tokens[_top];}
}
```